# Multiple if statements in a for loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, if-statement, for-loop

Help please, below is my code in Visual Basic.

My `for` loop does not go to the second `if` condition. It just checks for the first one. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

```
If Not dsMarketingOrdIDs Is Nothing Then
    For i = 0 To dsMarketingOrdIDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        If dtMarketingOrdIDs.Rows(i)("marketing_org_id") = 5 Then
            If Not objALUtil.CheckPermission("KBAUTHORXTREMESUPPORT") Then
                blnKbAuthorXtremeSupport = True
            End If
            If dtMarketingOrdIDs.Rows(i)("marketing_org_id") = 152 Then
                If Not objALUtil.CheckPermission("KBAUTHORXTREMEPORTAL") Then
                    blnKbAuthorXtremePortal = True

                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like that:

```
If Not dsMarketingOrdIDs Is Nothing Then
    For i = 0 To dsMarketingOrdIDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        If dtMarketingOrdIDs.Rows(i)("marketing_org_id") = 5 Then
            If Not objALUtil.CheckPermission("KBAUTHORXTREMESUPPORT") Then
                blnKbAuthorXtremeSupport = True
            End If
        End If
        If dtMarketingOrdIDs.Rows(i)("marketing_org_id") = 152 Then
            If Not objALUtil.CheckPermission("KBAUTHORXTREMEPORTAL") Then
                blnKbAuthorXtremePortal = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Or even easier:

```
If Not dsMarketingOrdIDs Is Nothing Then
    For i = 0 To dsMarketingOrdIDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        blnKbAuthorXtremePortal = Not objALUtil.CheckPermission("KBAUTHORXTREMESUPPORT") _
            AndAlso (dtMarketingOrdIDs.Rows(i)("marketing_org_id") = 5 OrElse dtMarketingOrdIDs.Rows(i)("marketing_org_id") = 152)
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an else if?

```
If Not dsMarketingOrdIDs Is Nothing Then
    For i = 0 To dsMarketingOrdIDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        If dtMarketingOrdIDs.Rows(i)("marketing_org_id") = 5 Then
            If Not objALUtil.CheckPermission("KBAUTHORXTREMESUPPORT") Then
                blnKbAuthorXtremeSupport = True
            Else If dtMarketingOrdIDs.Rows(i)("marketing_org_id") = 152 Then
                If Not objALUtil.CheckPermission("KBAUTHORXTREMEPORTAL") Then
                    blnKbAuthorXtremePortal = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Also, how can your MARKETING_ORG_ID be 5 and 152 at once??

dtMarketingOrdIDs.Rows(i)("marketing_org_id") = 5

dtMarketingOrdIDs.Rows(i)("marketing_org_id") = 152